# Quelle est la difference entre « se rendre compte » et « s'apercevoir » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Dans quelles situations peut-on utiliser ces mots ?

Y a-t-il une différence d'utilisation ou de sens ?

Par exemple, quelle est la différence entre :

> Je m'en suis aperçu mais trop tard.

et

> Je m'en suis rendu compte mais trop tard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mon interprétation est que *s'apercevoir* est la conséquence d'une réalisation soudaine, alors que *se rendre compte* peut aussi être le fruit d'une réflexion, d'un raisonnement.

Answer (score 4):

Pour compléter la réponse d'Alexis :

- *apercevoir* mettant en jeu la vue et ses réactions réflexes permettant une réponse immédiate suite à une perception des sens,
- *comprendre* afin de 'rendre compte', nécessitant de connaître et analyser une situation en passant par le mental (qui numérise ou codifie et culpabilise aussi) sans qu'il y ait nécessité de réagir.

Answer (score 4):

Personnellement, la seule différence que je fais entre les deux c'est que je me *rends compte* lorsque j'avais initialement une idée fausse de la situation, alors que je m'*aperçois* de quelque chose auquel je n'aurais pas nécessairement prêté attention.

Si je m'« aperçois qu'il fait nuit », tout va bien, il fallait bien que la journée se finisse tôt ou tard. Si je me « rends compte qu'il fait nuit », c'est peut-être que, sans le savoir, ce que j'étais en train de faire a pris plus de temps que prévu. Cela va possiblement changer mes plans.

De mon point de vue, rien à voir avec une quelconque réflexion. Rendez-vous compte… il n'est pas nécessaire de réfléchir bien longtemps pour comprendre qu'il fait nuit !

Answer (score 4):

Nous sommes tous vraisemblablement assez d'accord sur la nature de cette distinction. Il me semble qu'on pourrait la formuler comme ceci :

> **S'apercevoir** est l'arrivée d'un fait ou d'une idée dans **le champ de nos perceptions**.
>
> **Se rendre compte** est l'arrivée d'un fait ou d'une idée dans **le champ de notre conscience**. *(ce qui est un peu différent, dans la mesure où nous avons un grand nombre de perceptions mais notre conscience ne les appréhende pas toutes, et seulement successivement.)*

Comment: La formulation me plaît :-)